# JS How to handle cooldown in a browser game?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to make a browser game with some JS. I want some actions to be under cooldown. Like sending npcs to missions, etc. And I was wondering how to handle this ?

Is this about saving game state on client side ?

Comment: Unless you don't care about the user cheating it, store the cooldown time in the backend.

Comment: Anything wrong with `setTimeout`?